# Cross section on a surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have to make this graph

[image]
I have only managed to make one part, the rest is very complicated to graph. The graph at the top is supposed to be a surface and I'm taking a small curved plate. Any idea or help please? One thing I would like is for the arrows to be blue, not black as it appears on my graphic. I tried `fill=blue` but no success.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, arrows, decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .3 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}},
        mark=at position .7 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
      }}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-1.7,-1.2) rectangle (1.7,1.2);
    \draw (-1.5,-1) rectangle (1.5,1);
    \draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[red] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
    \foreach \a in {-4,-3,...,3}
    \draw[postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}, blue] (-2,1/8+\a/4) -- (2,1/8+\a/4);
    \draw[fill, red] (0,1) circle (0.3mm);
    \draw[fill, red] (0,-1) circle (0.3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will put my attempt here as an answer, I know I still have a lot to learn but here I leave it in case someone wants to see how it is done or wants to modify it:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, arrows, decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .35 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}},
        mark=at position .7 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
      }}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \s in {1/2} %scale
    {
    \foreach \c in {0} %Vertical displacement
    \foreach \d in {4*\s} %Horizontal displacement
    {
%Give color
    \fill[gray!50!white,opacity=0.2] (-3*\s+\c,2*\s+\d).. controls (-3*\s+\c,2*\s+\d) and (-3*\s+\c,4*\s+\d)..(-2*\s+\c,4.2*\s+\d)..controls (1*\s+\c,4*\s+\d) and (2*\s+\c,3.1*\s+\d)..(2*\s+\c,3.1*\s+\d).. controls (1*\s+\c,2*\s+\d) and (1*\s+\c,1*\s+\d)..(1*\s+\c,1*\s+\d).. controls (0+\c,2*\s+\d) and (-2*\s+\c,2*\s+\d)..(-3*\s+\c,2*\s+\d);
%contour
    \draw (-3*\s+\c,2*\s+\d).. controls (-3*\s+\c,2*\s+\d) and (-3*\s+\c,4*\s+\d)..(-2*\s+\c,4.2*\s+\d)..controls (1*\s+\c,4*\s+\d) and (2*\s+\c,3.1*\s+\d)..(2*\s+\c,3.1*\s+\d).. controls (1*\s+\c,2*\s+\d) and (1*\s+\c,1*\s+\d)..(1*\s+\c,1*\s+\d).. controls (0+\c,2*\s+\d) and (-2*\s+\c,2*\s+\d)..(-3*\s+\c,2*\s+\d);
%Surface drawing
    \draw (-4*\s+\c,-1*\s+\d)..controls (-6.5*\s+\c,-1.5*\s+\d) and (-6.5*\s+\c,2.5*\s+\d)..(-4*\s+\c,4*\s+\d)..controls (-1.1*\s+\c,5.9*\s+\d) and (2.5*\s+\c,4.8*\s+\d)..(5*\s+\c,2*\s+\d)..controls (6.5*\s+\c, 0.1*\s+\d) and (4*\s+\c,-4.5*\s+\d)..(2*\s+\c,-3*\s+\d)..controls (1.1*\s+\c,-2.5*\s+\d) and (-0.5*\s+\c,-0.5*\s+\d)..(-4*\s+\c,-1*\s+\d);
%Flow drawing
    \draw[postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}, blue] (-3.5*\s+\c, 2.2*\s+\d)..controls (-1.8*\s+\c,2.8*\s+\d) and (0.5*\s+\c,2.1*\s+\d)..(1.8*\s+\c,1.1*\s+\d);
    \draw[postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}, blue] (-3.4*\s+\c, 2.8*\s+\d)..controls (-1.5*\s+\c,3.1*\s+\d) and (0.4*\s+\c,2.7*\s+\d)..(1.9*\s+\c,1.7*\s+\d);
    \draw[postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}, blue] (-3.2*\s+\c, 3.4*\s+\d)..controls (-1.6*\s+\c,3.7*\s+\d) and (0.8*\s+\c,3.1*\s+\d)..(2.1*\s+\c,2.1*\s+\d);
    \draw[postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}, blue] (-2.9*\s+\c, 3.9*\s+\d)..controls (-0.9*\s+\c,4*\s+\d) and (0.8*\s+\c,3.7*\s+\d)..(2.2*\s+\c,2.6*\s+\d);
    \draw (-5.6*\s+\c,1.2*\s+\d)..controls (-5.7*\s+\c,-0.1*\s+\d) and (-5.4*\s+\c,-0.5*\s+\d)..(-4.7*\s+\c,-0.8*\s+\d);
    \draw (4.2*\s+\c,2.5*\s+\d)..controls (5*\s+\c,1.9*\s+\d) and (5.2*\s+\c,1.2*\s+\d)..(5.2*\s+\c,0.8*\s+\d);
    \draw[thick, red] (-1.3*\s+\c,1.1*\s+\d)..controls (-0.9*\s+\c,1.9*\s+\d) and (-0.9*\s+\c,3.9*\s+\d)..(0.4*\s+\c,4.2*\s+\d);
    }




    \foreach \x in {6*\s}
    \foreach \y in {-4*\s}
    {
    \fill[gray!50!white,opacity=0.2] (-3*\s+\x,-2*\s+\y) rectangle (3*\s+\x,2*\s+\y);
    \draw (-3*\s+\x,-2*\s+\y) rectangle (3*\s+\x,2*\s+\y);
    \draw (-4*\s+\x,\y) -- (4*\s+\x,\y);
    \draw[thick, red] (0+\x,-3*\s+\y) -- (0+\x,3*\s+\y);
    \foreach \a in {-2,-1,...,1}
    \draw[postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}, blue] (-4*\s+\x,1/2*\s+\a/2+\y) -- (4*\s+\x,1/2*\s+\a/2+\y);
    \draw[fill, red] (0+\x,2*\s+\y) circle (0.4mm);
    \draw[fill, red] (0+\x,-2*\s+\y) circle (0.4mm);
    \node at (-3.6*\s+\x,-1/8+\y) {$-\varepsilon$};
    \node at (3.4*\s+\x,-1/8+\y) {$\varepsilon$};
    \node[above right] at (0*\s+\x,2*\s+\y) {$+1$};
    \node[below right] at (0*\s+\x,-2*\s+\y) {$-1$};
    }
    
    
    \foreach \a in {-6*\s}
    \foreach \b in {-4*\s}
    {
    \draw (-4*\s+\a,0+\b) -- (4*\s+\a,0+\b);
    \draw (0+\a,-4*\s+\b) -- (0+\a,4*\s+\b);
    \fill[gray!50!white,opacity=0.2] (-3*\s+\a,2*\s+\b)..controls (-1*\s+\a,3*\s+\b) and (0+\a,1*\s+\b)..(2*\s+\a,2*\s+\b)..controls (2*\s\a,2*\s\b) and (1*\s+\a,0+\b)..(3*\s+\a,-2*\s+\b)..controls (1*\s+\a,-2*\s+\b) and (-1*\s+\a,-1*\s+\b)..(-2*\s+\a,-3*\s+\b)..controls (-3*\s+\a,-2*\s+\b) and (-4*\s+\a,0+\b)..(-3*\s+\a,2*\s+\b); 
    \draw (-3*\s+\a,2*\s+\b)..controls (-1*\s+\a,3*\s+\b) and (0+\a,1*\s+\b)..(2*\s+\a,2*\s+\b)..controls (2*\s\a,2*\s\b) and (1*\s+\a,0+\b)..(3*\s+\a,-2*\s+\b)..controls (1*\s+\a,-2*\s+\b) and (-1*\s+\a,-1*\s+\b)..(-2*\s+\a,-3*\s+\b)..controls (-3*\s+\a,-2*\s+\b) and (-4*\s+\a,0+\b)..(-3*\s+\a,2*\s+\b);
    \draw[blue, postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}] (-4*\s+\a,1*\s+\b)..controls (-3*\s+\a,2*\s+\b) and (0+\a,0+\b)..(3*\s+\a,2*\s+\b);
    \draw[blue, postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}] (-4*\s+\a,0+\b)..controls (-2*\s+\a,1*\s+\b) and (0+\a,-1*\s+\b)..(3*\s+\a,1*\s+\b);
    \draw[blue, postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}] (-4*\s+\a,-1*\s+\b)..controls (-3*\s+\a,0*\s+\b) and (1*\s+\a,-2*\s+\b)..(3*\s+\a,0+\b);
    \draw[blue, postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=black}}] (-4*\s+\a,-2*\s+\b)..controls (-2*\s+\a,-1*\s+\b) and (2*\s+\a,-2*\s+\b)..(3*\s+\a,-1*\s+\b);
    
    \draw[thick, red] (-2*\s+\a,3*\s+\b)..controls (0+\a,2*\s+\b) and (-2*\s+\a,-1*\s+\b)..(2*\s+\a,-3*\s+\b);
    
    \node at (-4*\s+\a,2.5*\s+\b) {$\mathbf{x}_\alpha(U_\alpha)$};
    }
    
    \draw[-stealth] (-1*\s, -2) to ++(2*\s,0);
    \node at (0,-1.75) {$h$};
    
    \draw[-stealth] (-2.4*\s,5.6*\s) to[bend right] ++(-2*\s,-7*\s);
        \node at (-2.6,0.9) {$\mathbf{x}_\alpha$};
        
    \draw[-stealth] (4.6*\s, -1.7*\s) to[bend right] ++(-3.2*\s,6.4*\s);
    \node at (2.5,0.2) {$\delta$};
    \node at (2,4) {$M$};
    \node at (0.4,4.12) {\textcolor{red}{$\Sigma$}};
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]